# Yield in recursion multiplayer

Tags: python, recursion

i just wrote this function and got error from the interpreter "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"
is it possible to use yield in this recursion?

```
def multiplyer(fir, sec):
    if(sec==1):
       return fir
    else: 
       return fir+multiplyer(fir, sec-1)
print(multiplyer(5, 2983))
```

Comment: But here your function is simply `fir*sec`...

Comment: No, you, uh, literally reached the maximum recursion. Try with a lower `sec` value and it will work.

Comment: you right. but there is a theoretical question: can i use generator for optimising this function?

Comment: generator wouldn't help, you would still have to go deeper to calculate the values. The difference between a generator and regular function is in the heap, not the stack.

Comment: @pinkychyaz: but you do not generate any lists (or some sequence of values). A yield is used to return an iterable thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `yield` at all (and as far as I know, it will not work anyway). Your `multiplayer` function is simply equivalent to:

```
def multiplayer(fir,sec):
    return fir*sec
```

furthermore `yield` will not make much difference since it will still result in a recursion error: after all you will still perform calls 2983 deep (which is usually too much for the call stack). Python also does not support *tail recursion optimization (TRO)*.

`yield` is used when you want use a *generator*. A generator produces several (it can be zero, one or more) values. Here however you need a single value (and you need it immediately). Say that you however use `yield` like:

```
def multiplyer(fir, sec):
    if(sec==1):
       yield fir
    else:
       yield fir+next(multiplyer(fir, sec-1))

print(next(multiplyer(5, 2983)))
```

it will not make any difference: you will still do the recursion and reach the bound.

Answer (score 1):

You run out of stack space since you let the function call itself 2983 times, which means you store that number of return addresses and arguments on the stack, which is just not reasonable.

If your requirement is to use recursion, you can reduce the recursion depth to *O(logn)* order by doing this:

```
def multiplyer(fir, sec):
    if sec==1:
       return fir
    elif sec==0:
       return 0
    else: 
       return multiplyer(fir, sec//2) + multiplyer(fir, (sec+1)//2)
print(multiplyer(5, 2983))
```

Or more efficiently, also reducing the number of recursive calls to *O(logn)* order:

```
def multiplyer(fir, sec):
    if sec==0:
       return 0
    elif sec%2 == 0: 
       return 2 * multiplyer(fir, sec//2)
    else:
        return fir + 2 * multiplyer(fir, sec//2)
print(multiplyer(5, 2983))
```

Comment: I don't think you here reduce the number of recursive calls: it is still *O(n)*. The maximum recursion depth is however *O(log n)*.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with recursion, you can check the maximum allowed recursion depth like:

```
 import sys
 sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

and the nice thing is you can also set it:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)
```

However, this says nothing about your code or if it is optimal for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion in Python where iteration will do. Generators optimize for *memory* usage, nothing else. They are slower than the alternatives, and do not provide any workarounds for the global recursion limit (which is actually a limit on the size of the call stack; non-recursive calls count towards the limit as well).

```
# Just demonstrating the conversion from recursion to iteration.
# fir * sec would be the most efficient solution.
def multiplyer(fir, sec):
    rv = 0
    while sec > 0:
        rv += fir
        sec -= 1
    return rv
```